# CSS: Using :target to change css on multiple ID's

Tags: html, css, target

I'm trying to pull off a pure HTML/CSS -based site, that uses :target to specify what to show.

So i have a menu, with 3 tabs in, that when the target is equal to the ID, the tab is highlighted or something:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="id01" class="content2">
        <a href="#id01">Menu1</a>
    </td>
    <td id="id02" class="content2">
        <a href="#id02">Menu2</a>
    </td>
    <td id="id03" class="content2">
        <a href="#id03">Menu3</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.content2 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.content2:target {
    background-color: #999;
}
```

While this works perfectly fine, i now wanna add a bit more to it.
I create 3 divs, with the same id's as above, and set their initial `visibility` to `hidden`, and the target id's `visibility` will then be changed to `visible`.

HTML:

```
<div id="id01" class="content">
<p>Text for menu1</p>
</div>
<div id="id02" class="content">
    <p>Text for menu2</p>
</div>
<div id="id03" class="content">
    <p>Text for menu3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.content:target {
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
}
```

These 2 things works perfectly fine when seperated, but if i add them all together, it only takes effect on the top-most-id (the id specified earliest in the code) and not on both, even though they have different classes. What is wrong and can it be done?

Sorry for the long introduction, but i figured it'd be needed to understand what i'm trying to pull off. I want to change the background on the targeted menu-tab, and at the same time change the visibility of the targeted div.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Jakub S' answer worked - however, i dont know if that limits some of things that could be done with it. Here's how it looks:

http://jsfiddle.net/jepperask/spjt8y5h/

Comment: maybe silly - but did you change to content instead of content2 of the ancor parent td?

Comment: Not sure i follow? What you see above, is stripped from a single file. :-)

Comment: I know they work seperatedly, because if i move the divs up, before the menu, then they change visibility, but the background-color isnt changed.

Comment: ah ok, why you must have them with the same id?

Comment: You can use :target to style, but it only targets the ID specified in the URL after # - so if i want one target to trigger changes on multiple elements, I will need the same ID - or as Jakub S. says, enclose both in a container with the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CSS Selectors Level 3

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#id-selectors

> What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such attributes can have the same value in a conformant document, regardless of the type of the elements that carry them; whatever the document language, an ID typed attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element.

So you can't have the same id set on two elements.

But maybe you could enclose both a menu item and a div in one element with the same ID? Otherwise this leaves you with just JavaScript.

Comment: Haha, it actually worked. Ill add a picture in the question. Thanks for your input. :-)